Scope Variable inside Python's Try, Except block
At first, i wrote my simple code as below:
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("what's x? "))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"x is not an integer!")
    else:
        break

print(f"x is {x}")

but i then i added few more words and f-string into it:
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("what's x? "))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{x} is not an integer!\nPlease enter an integer.....")
    else:
        break

print(f"x is {x}")

Now, i'm getting the below error:
NameError: name 'x' is not defined.
I tried to change some lines of code, and i think it's a problem of variable scope, i just want to know, why is this happening.

x is never assigned if the expression errors.

The case where the execution would go into the except ValueError block is if int(input("what's x? ")) raised an error. In this case, x = ... won't be processed, i.e. nothing will be assigned to x. But in this case, you are trying to access x. Which produces the error.
If anything, the exception contains information about the failed value, not x. So:
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"{e}\nPlease enter an integer.....")

The exception won't contain the "pure" value, but already its own message, so you may have to adjust accordingly. If you want the actual raw value for the message, you'll need to assign it to a variable first:
v = input("what's x? ")

try:
    x = int(v)
except ValueError:
    print(f"{v} is not an integer!\nPlease enter an integer.....")


As per comment, do something like this in 2 steps instead if you want to access x:
while True:
    x = input("what's x? ")
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{x} is not an integer!\nPlease enter an integer.....")
    else:
        break

print(f"x is {x}")

Examples:
what's x? hello
hello is not an integer!
Please enter an integer.....
what's x? 1.23
1.23 is not an integer!
Please enter an integer.....
what's x? 5
x is 5


Think of what's happening in the code and in which order.

code int(input("what's x? ")) executes
the result is then assigned to x
loop is broken
prints out x is {x}

Both steps 1 and 2 are catching an exception.
Now, your problem is that ValueError is raised on the step 1, so step 2 (assignment of the result to x) hasn't happened yet and x is not defined in your exception.
Hope it helps.
